# XAP file invalid

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have submitted my app in windows phone marketplace,here is the link

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/mywannado/23068282-3b9b-4cb2-aa6e-e2318b13f3a7

I have selected the India as market and the price is 0.0(free app)while submitting.

I tried to download it from my system, but it shows

"You can't get apps in this region. You can check the Windows Phone Store in your home region to see if the app is available there"

When i try too download the app from my mobile, i couldn't find the app in market place.
I am using Nokia Lumia510, and using this same account for the sign in at mobile.
So i tried "Download and install manually"

But that too failed,i can down load the "xap" file but, when i try to deploy it, it shows "XAP file is invalid".

Can you please give me a clarification why is this happening, and what should i do to install my app from marketplace.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution from another developer forum,
Actually we cant install the xap files downloaded from market place to the emulator,because its encrypted. we can install only the xap files from developer side.

Answer (score 0):

When I submitted my app to the Marketplace it took several days after the certification that it is appeared in the target region available for download.